# Can multiple user's data be shared through firebase? If yes how to do it?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

To understand my problem please do read following.

In my application, There will be multiple users. Let's take the example of a family. In a family, Father can book an appointment for his children to see a doctor and basically can be "care taker" of the family.
So, in my application all the members of the family will be users of the system and Father can have access to everyone's data. In future, the mother can also want to use the system and can become an active user of the system. So the data of the family must be shared with Father and Mother. (So no duplication of records.)

Is it possible to implement this type of system/ functionality using FireBase?

I am a newbie so please point me to the specific links and ask questions to get a clear idea of what I am trying to do. 
Thank you.

Comment: This would almost certainly be doable using [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).

Comment: The authentication will be with Mobile number for a user. So, Father has an account with his mobile number and in future, if the mother comes in with her mobile number then there should be some way to enable the mother to share all the data from fathers account. Is it also doable?

Comment: Every one will have a user page and also responsiblePersons id array. I mean If you want to add a user as child/parent (as you are responsible from) then request an approval dialogue. If that one is your child/parent then he/she will approve your request. Upon approval, his/her id will be added to your responsiblePersons array. So, this array will be a guide to access other users data.

Comment: Consider also setting custom claims on the "care taker" to give that user elevated access. This is described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims You would then enforce this with Firebase Rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly common use case; parents and children, departments and employees, vineyards and wines etc.

Here's one possible structure. Start with a node that stores all of the users, with a type that indicates what they are, care taker (parent) and child

```
users
  user_0
    type: "care taker"
  user_1
    type: "child"
  user_2
    type: "child"
  user_3:
    type: "care taker"
  user_4:
    type: "care taker"
```

Then a stucture that groups the users into logical family_units

```
family_units
  family_0
    user_0: true
    user_2: true
  family_1
    user_1: true
    user_3: true
```

The above defines two family units each one with a care taker (parent) and a child. Suppose we want to add an additional parent to family_1

```
  family_1
    user_1: true
    user_3: true
    user_4: true
```

That's about it. From there you would leverage [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) to enforce security - for example only allowing user_0 and user_2 to access the data in the family_0 node.

So yes, Firebase can do this task

Comment: Thank you. I am now able to get the ideas and able to understand Firebase, firestore concepts.